# Subtracting selected cell value from the average of previous 12 cells

Tags: r

I have a matrix (df) of 1565 rows and 132 columns. I need to locate a cell in df where the value is equal to `1`. Then subtract the "average value of preceding 12 cells" in the same row from the selected cell. These 12 observations may include the `NA` values as well. The output matrix (df1) is based on `NA` except the cell where the formula is applied. The formula is:

```
df[ selected value "1"] - df [average of preceding 12 cells' values]
```

See the sample:

```
df
 4    5    6    2    7    2    0    8    3    0    2    4    1
NA    4    2    0    3    1    3    4    3    6    5    0    0
2    NA    3    2    5    7    0    NA    0    2    0    3    1

df1:
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   -2.58
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  -1.25    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    -1.4
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Saba

Comment: Questions of this sort need to have a self contained minimal reproducible example including all inputs and your best attempt at code.  See [mcve]

Comment: I have provided a sample @G.Grothendieck. Will you please help me to find a code for this issue ?

Comment: In the future please provide theinput reproducibly by showing the R code that generates the input allowing anyone else to simply copy and paste it into their session to get the input  I have done it for you this time in the Note at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let us call the input `m` since the name `df` suggests that it is data frame whereas question indicates it is a matrix.  We have defined it reproducibly in the note at the end.

The problem seems to be to output a matrix of the same dimensions as the input such that for each input element that equals 1 replace it with 1 minus the mean of the prior 12 elements (or fewer than 12 if there are less than 12 available) in its row.  When the mean is calculated exclude NA elements.  For input elements not equal to 1 set the corresponding output element to NA.

This can be done by using the following function with `rollapplyr` from the zoo package.  Since it works by column we transpose the input and then transpose the output back.
.

```
library(zoo)

one.minus.avg <- function(x) { 
  n <- length(x)
  if (identical(x[n], 1)) 1 - mean(x[-n], na.rm = TRUE) else NA
}

t(rollapplyr(t(m), 13, one.minus.avg, partial = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]  [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]     [,13]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA -2.583333
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA -1.25   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA        NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA -1.400000
```

**Note:**  We used this for input `m`:

```
m <- matrix(c(4, NA, 2, 5, 4, NA, 6, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 7, 3, 5, 2, 
     1, 7, 0, 3, 0, 8, 4, NA, 3, 3, 0, 0, 6, 2, 2, 5, 0, 4, 0, 3, 
     1, 0, 1), 3)
```